# Symfony 3 : Doctrine:schema:update returns ConnexionException

Tags: pdo, doctrine

on a machine with IP 178.33.13.83, i have a symfony app with the following parameters.yml :

```
parameters:
database_host: 178.33.13.80
database_port: null
database_name: alterxtn
database_user: alterxtn
database_password: ********************
```

But then when i try to `doctrine:schema:update` i recieve the following exception :

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied 
for user 'alterxtn'@'178.33.13.83' (using password: YES)
```

I'm wondering why it's trying to connect to the machine the app is installed on and not on the database_host

**[Edit 1]:**

here the exception with stacktrace, and please notice especially the `Driver->connect()` function that's taking the good params :

```
ConnectionException in AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 103:
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'alterxtn'@'178.33.13.83' (using password: YES)


in AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 103
at AbstractMySQLDriver->convertException('An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'alterxtn'@'178.33.13.83' (using password: YES)', object(PDOException)) in DBALException.php line 145
at DBALException::driverException(object(Driver), object(PDOException)) in Driver.php line 47
at Driver->connect(array('driver' => 'pdo_mysql', 'host' => '178.33.13.80', 'port' => null, 'dbname' => 'alterxtn', 'user' => 'alterxtn', 'password' => '**********************************', 'charset' => 'UTF8', 'driverOptions' => array(), 'defaultTableOptions' => array()), 'alterxtn', '******', array()) in Connection.php line 360
```

**[EDIT 2] :**

i have the same error in shell so probably not a symfony problem

```
me@mymachine:$ mysql -h 178.33.13.80 -u alterxtn
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'alterxtn'@'178.33.13.83' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Are you using Symfony's dev-environment? If not, you're required to clear your application's cache after changing your parameters.yml

Comment: I cleared the cache thousands of times....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake.

The sql-user was set to server-privilege `localhost`
Setting it to `%` solved the issue.